# Compare rows of a given matrix with a fixed row vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

Say we have an N by 3 matrix A and a row vector v of length 3. I would like to end up with a column vector w of length N, such that the k-th entry of w is 1 if the k-th row of A is equal to v, and 0 otherwise.

A possible solution is

```
(A(:,1) == v(1))   .*   (A(:,2) == v(2))   .*   (A(:,3) == v(3))
```

but is there a more elegant way, or perhaps a matlab command that i do not know of? One that would also be nice if the number 3 is way larger?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not working, the multiplication throws a dimension mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
all(bsxfun(@eq, v, A),2)
```

Or [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)

```
ismember(A,v,'rows')
```